# Connection Refused Mailing Problem

Tags: email, email-server, connection

I'm trying to send emails through my server but it's not working.

I just setup this server and it's running ubuntu 10.04 lts

When I try to send an email it's telling me

Unable to connect to mail server: Connection refused(111)

I have no idea what to do.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) stop your firewall
2) post the output of "telnet localhost 25"
3) what mailserver are you using? post the conf file.

HTH...

Comment: I'm a complete noob and have no idea how to disable my firewall (i forget which one i installed as a matter of fact) Don't know what mail server im using, no idea how to post the config file or the output of telnet llocalhost 25 :D

Sorry I've never done this stuff before :(

Answer (score 0):

If you google for "Ubuntu 10.04 disable firewall", you will find [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/firewall.html) which says that you can run:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

to disable the firewall. This needs to be done from a Terminal. The [documentation about using the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) is quite helpful, and tells you how to open one if you don't know already. You can also type 1kstep's command there:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

and show the output that they requested. If you connect successfully then you can quit telnet again by pressing `Ctrl-]` (hold `Ctrl`, tap `]` once, release `Ctrl`), then enter, then `Ctrl-d`.

Read the Ubuntu documentation on [Postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix). Near the top of that page it says that the configuration file is stored at `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. You can open this file in [gedit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit) and then copy & paste the configuration.